# adding filestore to CRUD with 4.2.4 (existing examples obsolete?)

Tags: crud, atk4

I am trying to add file upload (filestore) to an existing CRUD page.

The examples I've found are all rather dated, and apparently filestore has changed enough where most of what you'll find is obsolete.

I did locate this tutorial video, which shows step-by-step how to implement filestore in sufficient detail that a relative novice (me!) was successful.

Filestore install begins at 0:34:30

[link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5dmAnvri1I&list=PL7CBF92AB03A1CA3B&index=9!

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did locate this tutorial video, which shows step-by-step how to implement filestore in sufficient detail that a relative novice (me!) was successful.

Filestore install begins at 0:34:30

[link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5dmAnvri1I&list=PL7CBF92AB03A1CA3B&index=9!