# How to upload file in server in Agiletoolkit Framework and Php

Tags: php, atk4, agiletoolkit

I am novice in Agile Toolkit Framework. I have done some portion like registration/login page in Agile Toolkit Framework with connecting with database and inserting the table in manually in database table. I cannot understand how to upload file in Agile Toolkit Framework.

**(1)** 
I have source file. I should contain the URL of the file that is then downloaded on the server and used in making the actual JSON file. Suppose you download a zip-file with 5 files in it. When chosen the server downloads the zip, opens it and provides the content in the other options.

**(2)**
When I choose 4 files of the 5 to be deleted, four lines in the JSON file will specify which files. I cannot understand how to do this type of issues. I have also reviewed https://github.com/romaninsh/upload for uploading file. I cannot understand where this zip/directory folder will be contained in latest version Agile Toolkit 4.2.4. Here, structure of the folder of romaninshupload is not same as in Agile Toolkit/example/blog or /dvdrental.

Answer (score 0):

Use [filestore](https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/tree/master/filestore) from atk4-addons.

[FileStore step by step example with 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755700/filestore-step-by-step-example-with-4-2-1)

[adding filestore to CRUD with 4.2.4 (existing examples obsolete?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947001/adding-filestore-to-crud-with-4-2-4-existing-examples-obsolete)

Comment: According 2 FileStore(4.2.1),I have run the sql in my database.And then I have created a newpage,filename.php under page folder and I have write the code,page_fileadmin extends filestore/Page_FileAdmin in filename.php and in my module I add this code $this->add('filestore/File').It is not working,it shows an error like Application Error:File not found.And then I have created another page action.php under page folder and have created another module Action.php under lib/Model/.Here User interface has been shown success fully.When the file is uploaded,it shows an error like Could not create file.

Comment: Where the Upload folder is put for uploading zip file in server. Another thing is that while uploading zip file, an error is coming. and how to insert in database table.I am novice in Agiletoolkit. I cann't understand how to do it.If any one knows about it, please reply me.

Comment: this video should help you
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5dmAnvri1I&list=PL7CBF92AB03A1CA3B&index=9